# Serving image assets from S3 in Ember app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, ember.js

I have a Rails server setup so that one of the views loads up the Ember app from S3 - something like below in my `application.html.erb`:

```
  ...
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= ember_assets.script_tag_for('vendor') %>
    <%= ember_assets.script_tag_for('my-ember-frontend-app') %>
```

and this in my `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method def ember_assets
    @ember_assets ||= begin
      asset_loader = EmberAssets::FileLoader.new # responsible for loading JS from S3

      EmberAssets.new(request: request, asset_loader: asset_loader)
    end
  end
  ...
```

The Javascript loads fine because my `EmberAssets` Ruby class correctly points to and loads up the JS files from S3. However, I have the logo and a few other default assets stored in `public/assets/images/...` and I read from them in my Ember app like so:

```
<img src="/assets/images/logo.png" alt="logo">
```

The problem is that while the JS is loaded correctly, the image files are not loaded from S3.

[image: the logo png request initiated by the built vendor.js fails with a 404]

How do I make it so that my Ember app reads default assets from S3 as well? I checked S3 and the asset is in the correct folder as expected with fingerprint and all.

[image]

I'm using Rails 6 and Ember 3.25 and I have installed these ember-cli-deploy addons for building and deploying my Ember app.

```
    "ember-cli-deploy": "^1.0.2",
    "ember-cli-deploy-build": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy-json-config": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-deploy-s3": "^3.0.0",
```

This is my build config. I tried to prepend my S3 bucket url but it didn't work:

```
module.exports = function (defaults) {
  let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    // Add options here

    fingerprint: {
      prepend: 'https://ember-s3-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/'
    }
  });
  ...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the compiled JS and the prepending worked. It turns out, I had neglected to copy over the new `index.json` created by my `ember deploy production` command, which means my rails server was pointing to old assets rather than the most recently deployed assets.

The gist is that you can add options to how you compile your Ember app [documented here](https://cli.emberjs.com/release/advanced-use/asset-compilation/) and that for my use case, all I needed was the `prepend` option.